# Derby Entity Relationship Diagram

Tags: derby, erd

Is there any free software out there for extracting the diagram of my derby database?
(Like MySQL Workbench for MySQL?)

Or maybe a plugin for netbeans?
Thank you

Comment: I would be interested in this as well. Mirth uses a Derby database by default, and it would be interesting to see its ERD.

Answer (score 3):

If it has a JDBC driver (derby has one), you can use any open source tool that does the diagrams you want and has JDBC support (most open source database tools support JDBC) . I like this one: [PowerArchitect](http://code.google.com/p/power-architect/downloads/list)

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for a solution there is a good open source plugin for NetBeans and gives you an ERD for your Derby database. Here is a link to download the plugin: https://java.net/projects/dber/downloads/directory/1.2

Not only there is a NetBeans plugin but they also have a standalone version.

Comment: For a full guide on how to install their plugin and connect it to your database I would recommend watching these two youtube videos:

[installing the plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZENiECPozc),

 [connecting plugin to database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1-KCCfiWBU)

Comment: Did you mean to put `goo open source`? Or should that be `good open source`?

Comment: sorry my bad, it was a typo, open source can only be GOOD not goo :)